# Remove Mask Placeholder Spacing Telerik RadMaskedNumericInput

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, telerik, controls

So with the Telerik RadMaskedNumericInput we can set the `Placeholder` property so the default display of for example `___123.45` can be replaced with something like `###123.45` by setting `Placeholder="#"` which is fine and dandy.

My issue is, I don't want the spacing caused by the `Mask` at all and instead would like the value to be left justified so it displays like for example, a normal `TextBox` and doesn't appear so out of place in a form.

Now then, I've dug through the Control Template (RadMaskedInputBaseStyle) and have tried setting all the relative alignments. I've tried just setting `Placeholder=""` so there's no space. However so far no joy from either and in fact trying to just set the Placeholder that way seems to just result in some funky overlapping.

Leaving the question, if say I have a `Mask` of #11.2, how can I get the display from this;

`|________123.45|`  = (Displaying a space for every `Mask` `Placeholder` spot with 8 spaces and then the number.)

into this;

`|123.45________|`  = (Displaying **without spaces** for the `Mask` `Placeholder` spots.)

Any insight appreciated. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It would appear after scouring the telerik docs that this is intended behavior and no workaround found so marking this answered.

Comment: Anonymous down-votes with no explanation help nobody, btw...

Answer (score 0):

This will not left align as intended by user, but gets rid of the placeholder entirly

```
    <Setter Property="Placeholder" >
        <Setter.Value>
            &#xFEFF;   <!--Unicode Character 'ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE' (U+FEFF)-->
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

Comment: Oh hey now that's clever! I'm going to have to check this out and get back to you. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like "&#xFEFF" at the last RadMaskedNumericInput works incorrectly, "&#x200B" (ZERO WIDTH SPACE) works good for me.